# Import Self Signed Certificates into Netty

Tags: ssl, openssl, netty

I need to set up SSL for my Netty server for which I am planning to use a self signed certificate. I wanted to know what are the steps involved in doing so ?

1. Use openssl to get a .key & .csr file.
   Do I need to convert the .csr file into pem ?
2. How do I import the the certificate in the keystore? Is that cacerts on a linux machine?
3. Do I also need to import the keys into the keystore?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows the steps for using a certificate signed by StartSSL:

http://blog.hintcafe.com/post/33709433256/https-server-in-java-using-netty-and-keystore

I think the steps can be modified for using your self-signed certificate (or you could sign it for free using StartSSL.